# Problems getting data from a local json file in React

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I have a React project with a local JSON file in my src folder. I'm using fetch and having issues getting to the file.

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "field1": "some data",
    "field2": 63,
    "field3": ["info", "info", "info"],
    "array1":[14, 35, 22, 22, 7],
    "array2": [8, 21,  14, 13, 5],
    "Link": "https://trailhead.salesforce.com"
  }
]

async function loadJSON (url) {
 const res = await fetch(url);
 return await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
}

loadJSON('../file.json')
 .then(data => {
 console.log(data);
});
```

[This is what I get in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QubRx.png)

[When my return statement is return await (res) I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsNvJ.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's local you can directly import it in your app like:

```
import data from './data.json'
```

Comment: So the JSON file is large, and I'll need to get a specific index for a button clicked. Wouls axios be best for that or fetch?